# Number of zeros in a number

Tags: algorithms

Is there a quick way of figuring out the number of zeros of some number? It's easy for numbers like: $10$, $100$, $1000$, but not so obvious when the number is something like: $32546200234029402340324324035648445345341233567862040$. Is there an algorithm for solving this in less than linear time?

Comment: Your question implies that you think that the number of zeroes in a number like 1000 can be calculated in less than linear time.  If you do think that, can you please explain how you think it can be done?

Comment: @MJD - I think he means linear in the number itself $O(n)$, not in the number of digits $O(\log(n))$

Comment: I mean linear in the number of digits. Look at every digit, if it's equal to zero increment the count, otherwise pass.

Comment: @nbubis That is ridiculous. If you have an $O(\log n)$ method then you automatically have an $O(n)$ algorithm by definition. And obviously there is an $O(\log n)$ algorithm for counting the number of zeroes, namely, to scan the digits and count the zeroes.

Comment: In a computer, the number will be stored in binary.  If you want the number of zeros in base 10, you will have to convert first.  Scanning the number in binary can be done, as well.

Comment: If you find a way of doing this in under linear time, let me know.  You would have discovered a way of finding the people associated with the numbers in phone books without looking at them one at a time.  You could conceivably put the number in a data structure optimized for this search, but that operation in itself requires $O(n)$ time.

Comment: @MJD You are right. I wrote that unconsciously because it was easy for me to compute it for $10$ and $1000$ but harder for the large number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An algorithm that ran in less than linear time wouldn't even be able to read all of its input. You would need an extremely problem-specific input encoding in order to be able to skip over any significant amount of input while being sure that the input you skip couldn't cause a zero to appear or disappear from the base-10 representation.

(But of course such a representation is *possible*. For example you can represent a string of decimal digits as a count of zeroes, followed by information about where the zeroes are, followed by the nonzero digits in their natural order).

Comment: If it can't be done in general. How can we prove it?

Comment: My second paragraph says it _can_ be done by choosing a sufficiently strange input encoding. But then again when we're talking about sublinear running times, an input encoding that strange would usually be considered to define a _different_ problem. So in order to produce a rigorous proof that there's no sublinear algorithm, you'd have to start by defining _exactly_ how the input to this algorithm is to be encoded.

Comment: You say it may be possible for problem-specific input. I mean what about general input. We don't assume anything about the input distribution.

Comment: @saadtaame: I'm not talking about distributions, but about the _encoding_ of the input to the algorithm. How does the input number get presented to the algorithm as a string of symbols from a finite alphabet?

Comment: Let's agree that the input is encoded as a string of characters.

Comment: @saadtaame: Yes, but there's an infinity of possible ways to represent numbers as strings of characters. The existence or not of a sublinear zero-counting algorithm might (and most certainly does) depend on which of them you want it to work with.

Comment: Shouldn't the input encoding be part of the problem statement?

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann: Yes, that's what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

There is no algorithm that can take as input the base-10 representation of a number and tell you how many zero digits it contains without examining each digit to see if it is a zero.  This is no "easier" for a number like 1000 than it is for a number like 3254: until the algorithm has examined all the digits in the input, it can't know how many are zeroes.

It is at least conceivable that by representing the input in a different format one might produce an algorithm that runs in less than $O(n)$ time. However, this direction is unlikely to lead to anything useful.  Henning Makholm's answer elaborates on this a little: if the representation of the input includes the count of zeroes explicitly, then there is an easy algorithm to count the zeroes: read in the count and emit it without reading the rest of the number.  But this is of course pointless since you need to know the number of zeroes to produce such a representation in the first place.